# check if an item is the same than the last i clicked / listview

Tags: java, android, listview

What i want to do is "simple", i click on an item in the listview, something happen . I click again on an item and depending on if it's the same item i clicked or another one it would do something else . Can you guys help me ?

```
public OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    int i = 1;
    int p;
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id){
        loaddetails(pf, position);
        i++;
        p=position;
        if(i%2 == 0 ){
            details.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.enter));
            details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            details.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade2));
            details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
};
```

My example is something like, i click on an item, details appears, details must disappears only if i click on the same item .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep an id placeholder of the last item clicked:

Global to the class:

```
int lastID = -1;
```

Then:

```
public OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    int i = 1;
    int p;
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id){
        loaddetails(pf, position);
        i++;
        p=position;
        if(lastID == id || lastID == -1){
            details.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.enter));
            details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            details.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade2));
            details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        lastID = id;
    }
};
```

Comment: it's almost working, but when i launch the app, i don't why but i need to click two times on an item to make it appear .

Comment: ah, you need to check for the default id.  I've updated my post.

Comment: Ok it's almost done, i know i sound like a noob but i've got another problem, what i want to do is : i click for the first time, it open details, if i click on the same it's gone . And if i had click on something else it would remain but details would be different .